# Git clone / submodule getting error 'is outside repository'

Tags: git, recursion, clone, git-submodules

**The problem**
I simply run a command `git clone --recursive <repo>` to clone a repo with submodules, it cloned the repo but failed when clone submodules. The error message is

`fatal: C:\Users\folderJobs: 'C:\Users\folderJobs' is outside repository`

The `folderJobs` was the previous folder name of this repo, I didn't have submodules at that time.

**Background**
I have a repo used to sync code from machine A to machine B, machine B is a server with Job Scheduler to run scripts form several projects. I previously manual maintained a `server_scripts` project which is the collection of all scripts from different project. This was not a perfect way, so I decided to add all projects as submodule in this `server_scripts` project. I suppose each I need to update to the latest version of scripts, just need to run

`git submodule update --recursive --remote`.

I made those changes on machine A (my workstation), then I got to machine B, deleted the `folderJobs`, because I wanted to clone a brand new copy. I run the `git clone --recursive` after deleted `folderJobs`. The previous folder name was different from the project name, but this time I would use the same folder name as project name.

I tried the same command on my machine A, it worked for different location of my file system.

**Question**

I suppose `clone` command is to create a brand new folder from the repo, but it seems the `Git` remembers something on my machine B.

Did anyone get the same error message when clone? I don't know how to resolve it after spend half day Googling.

Thanks for any information.

-- Additional information

1> I checked the Git version for both machine, small difference, was that the reason?

```
$ git --version
git version 2.14.1.windows.1

$ git --version
git version 2.12.2.windows.1
```

2> I tried to run the command in other folder on machine B, the same error

Answer (score 0):

> but it seems the Git remembers something on my machine B.

Double-check the content of your `.gitmodules` file in your repo: you don't want any absolute path in it.

Make sure also you don't have an hidden .git folder already present in C:\Users.

Comment: Hi VonC, thanks for the suggestion. I have checked the `.gitmodules`, only two remote repo address. There is no `.git` on the upper folder.

Comment: @ZhongDai can you check the difference in `git config -l` on both system?